# Model data not displayed on template - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Short Story: I have made two apps. Properties and Tenants within a django project. First I started rendering data from Property model to property_detail.html template and it works fine, but after I created & migrated the Tenants model, and I try to render data from there to property_detail.html it doesn't work. Yet it doesn't give me any errors. It just doesn't show up.

Models.py

```
import arrow
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from properties.models import Property


class Tenant(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(  # new
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)

    full_name = models.CharField("Full Name", max_length=255, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField("Description", blank=True)
    country_of_origin = CountryField("Country of Origin", blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(
        "Created on", auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    apartment = models.ForeignKey(
        Property,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='reviews',
    )

    rent_tenant = models.CharField(
        "Rent he/she pays", max_length=10, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """"Return absolute URL to the Contact Detail page."""
        return reverse('tenant_detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import TenantListView, TenantDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TenantListView.as_view(), name='tenant_list'),
    path('<uuid:pk>', TenantDetailView.as_view(), name='tenant_detail'),  # new
]
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin  # new
from .models import Tenant


class TenantListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):  # new
    model = Tenant
    context_object_name = 'tenant_list'
    template_name = 'tenants/tenant_list.html'
    login_url = 'account_login'  # new


class TenantDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):  # new
    model = Tenant
    context_object_name = 'tenant'
    template_name = 'tenants/tenant_detail.html'
    login_url = 'account_login'  # new
    permission_required = 'books.special_status'  # new
```

and here is the html template section where I need it to be rendered.

```
<li class="list-group-item">
{% if tenant.full_name %}
<b>Layout</b> <a class="float-right">{{ tenant.full_name }}</a>
{% endif %}
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">
{% if property.usable_sqm  %}
<b>SQM</b> <a class="float-right">{{ property.usable_sqm }}</a>
{% endif %}
</li>
```

The other app is EXACTLY the same. Basically I copy-pasted everything from there and then just changed the fileds and renamed all the fields from Property to Tenant (By that I mean all the functions and urls ... ) What seems to be the problem? Because by my logic this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The views.py document you have provided doesn’t have property_details.html template, instead it has tenant templates( you trying to render tenant objects into property template right?). I am not sure how you trying passing tenant model to property template from the code provided.

Why don’t you import tenant model into property views and pass whatever tenant objects you want to the property template?